# Boost Serialization MSVC 2015 do not compile in DEBUG mode

Tags: visual-c++, serialization, boost, visual-studio-2015

By some reason MSVC DO NOT compile boost serialization example with the following code:

```
class MyName
{
public:
    MyName(std::string _name, std::string _family_name)
        :name{ _name }, family_name{ _family_name }
    { }
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    { ar & name; ar & family_name; } std::string name; std::string family_name;
};

int main()
{
    // create and open a character archive for output
    std::stringstream  ofs;

    // save data to archive
    {
        MyName my_name("MyName", "FamilyName");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa << my_name;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }

    // save data to archive
    {
        MyName my_name("afsf", "dgsass");

        boost::archive::text_iarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa >> my_name;
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the follwing error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(enum boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code,char const *,char const *)" (??0archive_exception@archive@boost@@QAE@W4exception_code@012@PBD1@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > >::load<unsigned int>(unsigned int &)" (??$load@I@?$basic_text_iprimitive@V?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@archive@boost@@IAEXAAI@Z)  cpp11_cpp14_cpp17   D:\Projects_Programing\__Testing\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17\cpp11_cpp14_cpp17.obj  1
```

But when I compiled it in release mode.
I have read that it could happen due to MSVC STRICT mode, but I have tried and it does not work neither.

Have anybody got such error ?

Comment: I made up a simple `MyName` structure and it compiles fine for me. Please show your `MyName` class.

Comment: @lakeweb Below you can see implementation of MyName:             `class MyName
{
public:
   MyName(std::string _name, std::string _family_name)
      : name{ _name }, family_name{ _family_name }
   {

   }

private:

   friend class boost::serialization::access;
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
   {
      ar & name;
      ar & family_name;
   }

   std::string name;
   std::string family_name;
};`

Comment: Still compiles fine. I've run, I think it is SP3. A service pack that came out somewhere in the last half year. That is about the only thing I can think of from here. I only used two headers, `text_oarchive.hpp` and `text_iarchive.hpp`. How about you? And I'm using 1.62. You should have posted it all, it would help.

Comment: @lakeweb I use boost 1.62 either and SP3 too. You should understand that it happens only in Debug mode compilation. In addition I have put libboost_serialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
libboost_wserialization-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
libboost_exception-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib

Comment: Hi, I only tried with a debug build. I never look at what libraries get linked in as boost takes care of that well. I use a lib path: $(BOOST_LIB), So if you are linking by picking your libs, It sounds like one is missing. Don't add libs, just set your Linker->General->Additional Library Directories to your boost lib folder. Then you don't have to worry about what libs you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the reason of this error.
It happens when I tried to compile with flag /Za (means zero extension from MSVC for C++). 
When I removed this flag my code compiles succesfully.

@lakeweb Thank you for your help and support !!

Unfortunately I do not understand why some extensions from MSVC does allow to compile Boost, but without extentions it does not compile. It is very strange !!

Maybe it is either the bug on Boost side or on MSVC side.
Any assumption ?

Comment: Hi Denis, I'm catching up. It was not explicit in the docs but because (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx) [pragma says]  _Pragmas are machine- or operating system-specific by definition, and are usually different for every compiler._, it is probably that the lib pragma got disabled and so the lib was not linked.